# NSNumberFormatter/Logic flaw causing to not display or display 3 dots in my UILabel in a Calculator App

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been working on a **Calculator App**, but I found a logic flaw or something that I'm probably missing in the **NSNumberFormatter**.

The problem, basically if the user presses the dot (.) more than once the ULabel that is displaying my string gets erased and if it keeps pressing it display up to 3 dots (...)

**An Example** -> 234... or '      ' (blank/nothing)

So, these are my **NSNumberFormatter** functions that are taking care of converting my string in something like this 23,000 or 23,452.22 or 243,002,123 (just to handle the comma separator and no more than 6 decimal digits (just making it nicer)..

```
// take the current value of self.inputString, and use NSNumberFormatter to give us a @"1,234,567.89" string.
- (NSString *)fancyString {
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormat = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    numberFormat.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;

    numberFormat.groupingSeparator = @",";

    numberFormat.groupingSize = 3;

    [numberFormat setMaximumFractionDigits:6];

   // if([inputString isEqualToString:@"."])
    [numberFormat setDecimalSeparator:@"."];

    [numberFormat setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    return [numberFormat stringFromNumber:self.numericalValue];
} 

// ******** CONTINUE FORMATTER
// take the current value of self.inputString, and use NSNumberFormatter to give us a number, as a NSNumber, like 1234567.89
- (NSNumber *)numericalValue {

    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormat = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    [numberFormat setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    self.number = [numberFormat numberFromString:self.Screen.text];

    return [numberFormat numberFromString:self.inputString];
}
```

Now, just for your reference and better understanding of my program this how I'm handling each digit that is pressed on the calculator.. ( it repeats the same way for all digits)

```
// ********* WHEN A BUTTON OR NUMBER OR DIGIT IS PRESSED... (THE SAME FOR ALL NUMBERS)
-(IBAction)Number9:(UIButton *)sender{
    [self appendDigit:@"9"];
}

-(IBAction)Number0:(UIButton *)sender{
    [self appendDigit:@"0"];
}

// ********** THIS FUNCTION IS PART OF MY PROBLEM BECAUSE GETS CALL WHEN THE . IS PRESSED..
- (IBAction)Dot:(UIButton *)sender {    
    self.currentText = Screen.text;
    if ([currentText rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch].length == 0) {
        [self appendDigit:@"."];
    }

}
```

Last, **AND THE MOST IMPORTANT!!!** where the logic flaw that it could be happening if the problem its not related to my **NSNumberFormatter**, here is how I append each digit to my string and then display it to my **UILabel**..

```
//********** THEN THIS WHERE I APPEND OR CONTROL THE DISPLAY OF MY LABEL WITH THE FUNCTION appendDigit.. AND WHERE THE PROBLEM IS..

// THE PROBLE IS BECAUSE IM USING A FORMATTER FOR A FANCY STRING EXAMPLE -> 2,500 or 325,000,200 IF THE DUMMY USER PRESSES THE . (Dot) MORE THAN ONCE WHEN THE LENGTH OF MY LABEL IS 3+ THEN THE fancyString function GETS CALL BUT IT WONT HANDLE THE CASE OF MORE THAN ONE TIME THE . (Dot) IS PRESSED AND IT WILL CAUSE FIRST A FUNNY BLANK OUT SCREEN (nothing displayed) AND THEN IF PRESSED AGAIN .. or more (Dots) are displayed on the screen :( so bad!!!! indeed!! need helpt to fix it... PLEASE!!!!!!!

- (void)appendDigit:(NSString *)digit {

        // appending each digit to my string to be formatted later
        self.inputString = [self.inputString stringByAppendingString:digit];

        if([self.Screen.text length] > 0 && [self.Screen.text length] <= 15) {

            if([self.Screen.text length] > 2){    
                // displays and calls formatter for fancy or nice display of string
                self.Screen.text = [self fancyString];
            } else {
                // just display the digits appended so far
                self.Screen.text = inputString;
            }
}
```

**Note:** I tried to toggle the call of my function **fancyString** but I couldn't make it work to avoid the user to keep pressing the dot (.) and the string gets affected by it..

I will really appreciate help, inputs, suggestions and everything that could let me to solve this..

Thanks,
NorthBlast :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing the problem this way but if someone has a better approach please let me know..!!!

```
- (void)appendDigit:(NSString *)digit {

    self.inputString = [self.inputString stringByAppendingString:digit];

    self.currentText = inputString;

    if([digit isEqualToString:@"."])
        controlDotFunction = YES;

        if([self.Screen.text length] > 0 && [self.Screen.text length] <= 15) {

            if(controlDotFunction && [self.Screen.text length] > 2) {

                self.Screen.text = [self.Screen.text stringByAppendingString:digit];
                controlDotFunction = NO;                                    

            } else {

                self.Screen.text = [self fancyString];

            }
}
```